# create cloudwatch dashboard with boto3 using lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

i want to create cloudwatch dashboard for multiple EC2 i have problem to put JSON dashboard bady and make region and id instance value be variable

the code

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json

import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    CW_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='eu-west-1')

    regions = [region['RegionName']
               for region in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    for region in regions:
        print('Instances in EC2 Region {0}:'.format(region))
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)

        instances = ec2.instances.filter(
            Filters=[
                {'Name': 'tag:backup', 'Values': ['true']}
            ]
        )
        for i in instances.all():
            #for ID in i.InstanceId.all():
            print(i.id)
            instance_id = i.id
            response = CW_client.put_dashboard(DashboardName='test', DashboardBody='{"widgets": [{"type": "metric", "x": 12, "y": 0, "width": 12, "height": 6, "properties": {"metrics": [[ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", instance_id ]], "view": "timeSeries", "stacked": false, "region": region, "stat": "Average", "period": 60, "title": "CPUUtilization" }}]}')
```

the error

```
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterInput) when calling the PutDashboard operation: The field DashboardBody must be a valid JSON object",
  "errorType": "DashboardInvalidInputError",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DashboardBody` contains the literal string `instance_id` and `region` (without quotes). That's why the JSON is invalid. You need the **values** of `instance_id` and `region`, not the bare words `instance_id` and `region`.

You should use string interpolation. For example:

```
region = "us-east-1"
instance_id = "i-1234567890"

partbody = '{"region":"%s", "instance_id":"%s"}' % (region, instance_id)
```

Or you could use f-strings but then you'd have to quote the braces, like so:

```
partbody = f'{{"region":"{region}", "instance_id":"{instance_id}"}}'
```

Both options result in a string that looks like this:

```
{"region":"us-east-1", "instance_id":"i-1234567890"}
```

Note that I'm showing you how to use string interpolation to inject variable values into a string. Now you need to do this and inject both `region` and `instance_id` into the `DashboardBody` string. For example:

```
DashboardBody='{"widgets": [{"type": "metric", "x": 12, "y": 0, "width": 12, "height": 6, "properties": {"metrics": [[ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId","%s" ]], "view": "timeSeries", "stacked": false, "region":"%s", "stat": "Average", "period": 60, "title": "CPUUtilization" }}]}' % (instance_id, region)
```

Comment: the two solution give me error the first give me that (  "errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'tuple'",
)
and the second solution (  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': f-string: expressions nested too deeply (lambda_function.py, line 27)",
)

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: python version 3.8

Comment: Removed extraneous brace from first example, but neither give runtime errors. Are both `region` and `instance_id` in your code actually valid strings (like my example code)?

Comment: sorry what you mean with extraneous brace . yes ,instance_id and region are strings

Comment: Both examples I showed you work correctly in Python 3.8. Try it in the Python REPL. I've updated my answer to show you what the resulting string `partbody` looks like. If you're unable to get this working then please re-post your latest code above along with the error messages so we can see what you are actually running.

Comment: thank you very very much for your efforts . the code work

Answer (score 0):

```
Your json body for 'DashboardBody' should be like this:

    {
       "widgets": [
          {
             "type": "metric",
             "x": 12,
             "y": 0,
             "width": 12,
             "height": 6,
             "properties":{
                "metrics":[
                   [
                      "AWS/EC2",
                      "CPUUtilization",
                      "InstanceId",
                      instance_id
                   ]
                ],
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false,
                "region": regions,
                "stat": "Average", 
                "period": 60, 
                "title": "CPUUtilization"

             }
          }
       ]
    }

Also You were passing incorrect value for "region" parameter, it should be regions (as declared in your code) and not region.
```

Comment: i thank that is not the problem because when i put the value of  region and instance_id the code work